# Do I use FBML to create a tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-fbml

I want to create a tab on a Facebook Fan page that will display a menu (PDF or embedded link to the website)...Do I use FBML for this? If so, where can I get a quick tutorial? Thank you for your time everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the Static FBML application: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?v=info&id=4949752878

This application allows you to put any valid FBML on a fan tab page.

FBML is essentially just HTML with a few custom tags. You can find a guide on it here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBML

Good luck!

Comment: @Gdeglin- Hey thanks for your help! I really appreciate it. Have a good one.